# Library wrapping Win32 does not open window in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2015

So I have been working on a library that uses the Win32 api to create a window, allowing the user of the library to open a window (essentially) like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Game game(800, 600, "Hello World");
    game.start();
}
```

Now, the code I have at the moment works fine, but only if I run the exe (with the library linked as a dll) outside of Visual Studio. If I attempt to run it *inside* Visual Studio, using the debugger, the program runs, but no graphical window is opened. Any console output is all correct, meaning the program is running correctly, there is just no shown graphical window.

I have tried changing the subsystem and I have tried implementing WinMain myself as what SFML does [here](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Main/MainWin32.cpp) but neither have worked, and as I am really not remotely experienced with the Win32 API (this is more of an educational project than anything serious) I am completely out of ideas, and I cannot find anything similar at all anywhere, which seems odd.

Can anybody provide any help, or pointers onto something obvious that I may have missed?

---

The window creation code is:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wndClass.style = 0;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = &Window::staticProc;
wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
wndClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
wndClass.lpszClassName = wndClassName;
wndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
RegisterClassEx(&wndClass);

int chars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, title.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0);
wchar_t* wTitle = new wchar_t[chars];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, title.c_str(), -1, wTitle, chars);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0, wndClassName, wTitle,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, w, h,
    nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, this);

STARTUPINFO info;
GetStartupInfo(&info);
ShowWindow(hWnd, info.wShowWindow);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create window console inside main win32 window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068392/create-window-console-inside-main-win32-window)

Comment: If the code is relevant, post it in your question. There's little value in a question linking to inaccessible off-site content, or content that no longer exhibits the problem.

Comment: @DanKorn: The question you linked to is unrelated.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough, I'll edit it in

Comment: Is it?  The OP says, "Any console output is all correct, meaning the program is running correctly, there is just no shown window."  So where is the console output then?  I guess we need to see the code "that uses the Win32 api to create a window."

Comment: @DanKorn I guess I should be more specific; a console window is shown, but not a graphical one.

Comment: There's no error checking on the `RegisterClassEx` call. Does it succeed? Likewise, there's no error checking on the `CreateWindowEx` call.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I checked it, I left out the error checking in the above code

Comment: One difference you get when running code inside vs outside Visual Studio is the current directory is often different.

Comment: If you have multiple projects in your solution, make sure to activate the correct project you'd like to run.

Comment: @Lukas The executable is correctly active, if it wasn't I wouldn't be seeing the console output I expect.

Comment: Please don't post fake code. Please show mcve.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most problems that I haven't seen recently, but which used to be real, was windows located off-screen. That would appear like your description "does not open" while in fact the window was open.

For this reason, I strongly recommend running Visual Studio on your second monitor so your own program has the primary monitor available. Don't try to debug GUI's without an extra screen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the vs2015 debugger as described in the accepted answer at [STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow is 0 when running from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953886/startupinfo-wshowwindow-is-0-when-running-from-visual-studio)

Try setting the `Use Native Compatibility Mode` option at Tools | Options | Debugging | General.