# STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow is 0 when running from Visual Studio

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I stumbled upon an issue while debugging a feature in an open-source Notepad replacement called Notepad2 (more specifically, a more recent fork called [Notepad2-mod](https://github.com/XhmikosR/notepad2-mod)).

It has a flag `/u` that causes the app to restart itself under Administrative privileges (using `runas` verb with ShellExecute). The code looks like this (snipped for brevity):

```
STARTUPINFO si;
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;

si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
GetStartupInfo(&si);

ZeroMemory(&sei,sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
...
sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
sei.lpFile = lpArg1;
sei.lpParameters = lpArg2;
sei.nShow = si.wShowWindow;

ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

For some reason, if I launched this from Visual Studio (with or without a debugger attached), the elevated child process' main window would just not show! It would appear in Process Explorer, but had no visible windows.

Upon investigation, I realized that the `nCmdShow` passed to the child process' `WinMain` was 0 (which corresponds to `SW_HIDE`) when started from Visual Studio! This value was subsequently passed to `ShowWindow`, and that's why it didn't show.

When trying to launch this from a cmd shell, everything worked fine.

Upon further investigation, it turned out that the value of `si.wShowWindow`, obtained by a call to `GetStartupInfo` was 0 when running in VS, but was 1 when started from a cmd:

[image: Launched from a cmd]

According to [STARTUPINFO MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx), the value for `wShowWindow` should match the value of `nCmdShow` if `dwFlags` has `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` in it. However, in both cases (launching from VS and cmd), the value for `dwFlags` was 0.

So, is this an issue with VS or am I just holding it wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know, why it even makes a difference what values are passed through the `STARTUPINFO` or the `wShowWindow` argument. It is ignored, the first time an application calls [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx). I suppose Notepad2 does something "unusual", i.e. calling `ShowWindow` more than once for its main application window.

Comment: The value of `wShowWindow` was passed into `sei.nShow`, and subsequently into the WinMain of the child process. Since the value was 0, the `nCmdShow` parameter of WinMain was also 0. This parameter was then passed to CreateWindow, so it effectively got called with SW_HIDE. Given what @HansPassant said below, it's possibly a bad practice to use nCmdShow directly, but that is what Notepad2 did.

Comment: Since there is no direct mapping between [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) and the values for *nCmdShow* available to [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx), I'd say the bug really is in Notepad2 (and Visual Studio, but that's somewhat irrelevant). Unless there's a striking reason for Notepad2 to use the flag for what it isn't supposed to be used, I'd suggest to change that.

Comment: Wait, is that code just using the value of `STARTUPINFO.wShowDefault` without checking the flags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll write this one up, it is a pretty awesome bug.  It is specific to the VS2015 debugging engine, it is quite notorious for having rather a lot of bugs.  Something you can see for yourself by disabling it.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Native Compatibility Mode" option.  That forces an older debugging engine to be used, you now consistently get STARTUPINFO.nCmdShow == SW_SHOWNORMAL.

There is a wee corner-case to reason that this was intentional, blindly following the nCmdShow advice is not advisable.  It is a malware attack vector, allowing it to start a program without the user noticing.  Many programs intentionally ignore SW_HIDE, not a very intuitive thing to do and very easy to overlook.  You need a glass that's well over half-full to make that interpretation however, the nCmdShow argument to WinMain() is what is normally used and it is correct.

Which is also the workaround that you can use.  Of course in this specific case you should never rely on the startup value and pass SW_SHOWNORMAL or SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED depending on the current state of Notepad++'s main window.

So I vote bug, use connect.microsoft.com to report it.  Put a link to the feedback article in a comment and we'll vote for it.

Comment: Great explanation! You can also use the Send Feedback option in VS, it's being regularly looked at!

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. What is the best thing to do? I thought the runtime computed `nCmdShow` to `WinMain()` using `STARTUPINFO`, defaulting to `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` if the respective flag bit is not set. I know the `ShowWindow()` documentation talks about using `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` or that the exact value is ignored, so I'm now confused what is the real correct thing to do, both for the initial window and any other non-owned toplevels in the program...